# CSS slow opacity fade has borders only in FF during transition

Tags: css, firefox, opacity, fade

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced. I wasn't able to find any concrete answers. I'm trying to do a slow fade on a span with a background and for some odd reason, in Firefox, there's a border (usually only one one side) that appears during the transition but it's not there after the transition is finished. I'm doing this with pure CSS.

Here's the CSS:

```
#lab_equip span {cursor:pointer;display:block;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;background:url(images/lab_active.png) no-repeat;background-size:cover;opacity:0;transition:all 1s;-moz-transition:all 1s;-webkit-transition:all 1s;-o-transition:all 1s;}
#lb-listen{width:28.06415%;left:0;}
#lb-brainstorm{width:22.1077%;left:28.1%;background-position:35.9% 0% !important;}
#lb-develop{width:28.29324%;right:21.6%;background-position:69.6% 0% !important;}
#lb-212{width:21.53494%;right:0;background-position:99.8% 0% !important;}
#lab_equip span:hover{opacity:1;}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="lab_txt">
            <div rel="lb-default"><?php $a = new Area('Default Text'); $a->display($c); ?></div>
            <div rel="lb-listen"><?php $a = new Area('Listen Text'); $a->display($c); ?></div>
            <div rel="lb-brainstorm"><?php $a = new Area('Brainstorm Text'); $a->display($c); ?></div>
            <div rel="lb-develop"><?php $a = new Area('Develop Text'); $a->display($c); ?></div>
            <div rel="lb-212"><?php $a = new Area('212 Text'); $a->display($c); ?></div>
        </div>
```

Just curious if anyone else has seen this happen. It works fine in Chrome.

Thanks for any tips! :D

Comment: Can you put together a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hey Adrift! I tried to do it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wgZpF/ but it's not reading the dynamic part. :( I accidentally pasted the wrong HTML above. (The two are so alike).